# Regex to extract two dates out of a date range

Tags: python, regex

I have a date range and I want to extract the two dates, this is an example string:

```
Sep 25-28, 2016
```

and I'd like to have two regular expressions, one that matches:

```
Sep 25, 2016
```

and the other that matches:

```
Sep 28, 2016
```

But then I'd like that also matches:

```
Sep 29-Oct 2, 2016
```

This is what I have built so far:

```
(?P<date>\b(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|[0-9]|1[0-2]) (\d|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\s|\.|-)(:?\d|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]),?(\s|\.|-)\b\d{1,4}\b)
```

But of course matches the whole range.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you need to _identify_ date ranges within a larger body of text?  You stated _I have a date range_, so it's unclear whether you need help determining if a given piece of text is a date range, or if you've solved that part and just need help _generating the full start and end dates_ from a range.

Comment: Short comment: `Sep 25-28, 2016` doesn't contain `Sep 25, 2016` and `Sep 28, 2016`. So, it would never match.

Comment: @JohnGordon, That is part of a larger text and I'd like to extract the two dates, the _start and the end date_.

Comment: @putvande for now I'm working on this:
`(?P<date>(((\d{1,2})){2}), \d{2,4})` that matches:
`28, 2016`

Comment: @PaoloC That didn't answer my question. When you're scanning through the larger text, are you able to identify the date ranges?  Or is that part of what you need help with?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am able to get dates ranges in general with this regex:
`(?P<daterange>\b(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|[0-9]|1[0-2]) (\d|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\s|\.|-)(:?\d|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]),?(\s|\.|-)\b\d{1,4}\b)`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your sample ranges, it looks like they follow this pattern:

`BEGIN_MONTH` `SPACE` `BEGIN_DAY` `DASH` `END_MONTH (optional)` `END_DAY` `COMMA` `SPACE` `YEAR`

From that, you want to generate two strings:

`BEGIN_MONTH` `SPACE` `BEGIN_DAY` `COMMA` `SPACE` `YEAR`

`END_MONTH (if present; otherwise use BEGIN_MONTH)` `SPACE` `END_DAY` `COMMA` `SPACE` `YEAR`

Is this correct?  Do you need to account for beginning and ending year, if a date range spans across a year boundary?

```
import re

pattern = '(\w+) (\d+)-(\w+ )?(\d+), (\d+)'
pc = re.compile(pattern)

text = 'Sep 25-Oct 5, 2016'
# text = 'Sep 25-29, 2016' -- also works in this format

if pc.match(text).group(3):
    # second month name is present
    print ('%s %s-%s%s, %s' % (pc.match(text).group(1),
                                pc.match(text).group(2),
                                pc.match(text).group(3),
                                pc.match(text).group(4),
                                pc.match(text).group(5)))

else:
    print ('%s %s-%s %s, %s' % (pc.match(text).group(1),
                                pc.match(text).group(2),
                                pc.match(text).group(1),
                                pc.match(text).group(4),
                                pc.match(text).group(5)))
```

Comment: John that is correct, how to translate that into a regex?

Comment: I was looking to do that without using any python coding, I have a system which any regex matches an information that is stored in an email. Usually this is found in this emails as:
`
    Start date: Sep 9, 2016
    End date: Sep 28, 2016
`
but in this case I have:
`
    Dates: Sep 9-28, 2016
`
You understand that I'd like to find a regex that matches `Sep 9, 2016` and another that matches `Sep 28, 2016`

Comment: _I was looking to do that without using any python coding_ Erm, then why did you tag your question with `python`?

Comment: sorry, mistyped

Comment: did you see that the question was not complete?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _the question was not complete_.  Do you mean that you have not approved an answer?

Comment: two things:
1) You replied the question before I was able to edit it so I wanted to be sure you could read it all
2) I tagged python because I am using regex in python, so I need that the regex should work in this environment, for example the `\K` command will probably solve my problem but is NOT available within the python regex engine.

Comment: I'm really confused what you're trying to say here.  If the question is not complete, then you should go edit it.  (Which as far as I can see you have not done.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using different regex for each possibility, and test them in order.  This will result in a much simpler program (with test cases).  Otherwise, the regex would be monstrous.

```
import re

RE1 = re.compile(r"(\w+)\s*(\d+)\,\s+(\d+)")  # Month day, year                              
RE2 = re.compile(r"(\w+)\s*(\d+)\-(\d+)\,\s+(\d+)")  # Month day-day, year                   
RE3 = re.compile(r"(\w+)\s*(\d+)\-(\w+)\s+(\d+)\,\s+(\d+)")  # Month day - Month day, year                                                                                                   


def date_interval(t):
  match1 = RE1.match(t)
  match2 = RE2.match(t)
  match3 = RE3.match(t)
  if match1:
    month1 = month2 = match1.group(1)
    day1 = day2 = match1.group(2)
    year = match1.group(3)
  elif match2:
    month1 = month2 = match2.group(1)
    day1 = match2.group(2)
    day2 = match2.group(3)
    year = match2.group(4)
  elif match3:
    month1 = match3.group(1)
    day1 = match3.group(2)
    month2 = match3.group(3)
    day2 = match3.group(4)
    year = match3.group(5)
  else:
    month1 = month2 = day1 = day2 = year = ''
  return ( day1, month1, day2, month2, year )


texts = (
  'Sep 25, 2016',
  'Oct 12-23, 2017',
  'Jan 15-Feb 26, 2018',
)

for t in texts:
  print t, date_interval(t)
```

this prints (python2)

```
Sep 25, 2016 ('25', 'Sep', '25', 'Sep', '2016')
Oct 12-23, 2017 ('12', 'Oct', '23', 'Oct', '2017')
Jan 15-Feb 26, 2018 ('15', 'Jan', '26', 'Feb', '2018')
```

You could easily extend the program if you need to parse dates with different years.

You could also replace `\w` with the months, as you did in your post (`Jan|Feb|...`).